# After animating EditText, keyboard no longer pans view

Tags: java, android, animation, keyboard

I have an EditText that gets covered by the soft keyboard when it is shown. This particular EditText can also be animated further down the screen when certain UI elements need to be shown before it.

If the EditText has not been animated, when the keyboard is shown, the entire view gets animated up so that it is no longer covered. However, after the EditText has been animated down, and the keyboard is shown, the view no longer moves up to uncover the EditText, not even by the amount that it would have taken to uncover it prior to the animation.

Here is the code I am using to animate the EditText:

```
findViewById(R.id.myEditText).animate().translationY(100f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your wording is a little confusing so I'm gonna try and clarify some stuff to make sure my answer is correct.

I'm reading this as, you have a view that is an EditText view. You also have some other UI elements that are sometimes added to the screen, sometimes not. Then you mention "the entire view gets animated up" when the keyboard is shown. I'm assuming you mean the viewGroup? As in, the other UI elements as well as the editText are all in one parent view, or viewGroup like a linear/relative layout or something. If so, your problem could be pretty simple.

Assuming that all the UI elements, as well as the editText are part of a parent view/viewGroup, then your problem could be the translationY(). Two issues I can see with using it. First, if your initial animation moves the editText outside of its parent view, then it could be cut off from the screen. That's an easy fix by adding the following code to its parent view:

```
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

The other issue could be that you're moving the editText to a specific position relative to its parent view by using translationY(). TranslationY(x) moves the view x pixels below its parent view. So if you've moved the editText's parent view, and then use translationY(100f) it will take the editText to a different location than if you had not moved the parent view. An alternative could be to use translationYBy(x) which moves the view x pixels from its CURRENT location.

In summary, translationY(100f) moves the view to the location that is 100 pixels below its parent. TranslationYBy(100f) moves the view down by 100 pixels no matter where it is. If you move the view outside the realm if its parent, you'll need to add those two lines I mentioned earlier so that they don't get cut off.